# How do I prove $(f^*)^{-1}=(f^{-1})^*$ if $f:V\rightarrow W$ is isomorphism

Tags: linear-algebra

I have to prove the following question but I'm quite lost on how to prove it.

The question: Let V and W be finite-dimensional inner product spaces. Show that if $f:V\rightarrow W$ is isomorphism (not necessarily isometry), then $$(f^*)^{-1}=(f^{-1})^*$$

My try:

We know that f is isomorphism, so it is surjective. Now, let $u∈V$. Since f is surjective, $u=fw$ for some vector $w$.

If $v∈V$,then
$⟨(f^{−1})^∗v,fw⟩=⟨v,f^{−1}fw⟩=⟨v,w⟩$

and $⟨(f^*)^{−1}v,fw⟩=⟨f^*(f^*)^{−1}v,w⟩=⟨v,w⟩$.

Since $(∀u,v∈V):⟨(f^{−1})^*v,u⟩=⟨(f^*)^{−1}v,u⟩$, we have $(f^{−1})^*=(f^*)^{−1}$.

I feel like this is completely wrong, so if someone could help I would appreciate it.

Comment: How $u=fw$ given that $f \colon V \to W$? *Hint*: Prove that if $E_1 \stackrel{T}\to E_2 \stackrel{S}\to E_3$ are linear maps between inner product spaces, then $(ST)^* = T^*S^*$. Also, for any inner product space $E$, prove that $(\operatorname{id}_E)^* = \operatorname{id}_E$.

Comment: @azif00 Sorry I meant to saw for some w. Forgot to correct that part before posting the question.

Comment: It still makes no sense, the image of $f$ lies in $W$, so $u$ cannot be in its image!

Comment: @azif00 Oh I see. So that only works when f is linear operator on V? I have to admit that I'm still confused by this task. I tried to understand and try your hint, but couldn't get anything out of it.

Answer (score 1):

What is $f^*$? It is the map that takes $\psi\in W^*$ and sends it to $(\psi\circ f)\in V^*$.

What is $(f^{-1})^*$? See that $f^{-1}$ is a bijective function from $W$ to $V$. Therefore, $(f^{-1})^*$ is the map that takes $\chi\in V^*$ and sends it to $(\chi\circ f^{-1})\in W^*$.

**It is obvious that $(f^{-1})^*$ is the inverse of $f^*$.** Verification:

$(f^{-1})^*\circ f^*$ sends $\psi\in W^*$ to itself.

Also, $f^*\circ (f^{-1})^*$ sends $\chi\in V^*$ to itself.

Therefore, $f^*$ is a bijection, and its inverse is $(f^{-1})^*$.

$\\$

**Thus, $(f^*)^{-1}= (f^{-1})^*$. The left-hand side of the equation is the definition of the inverse of $f^*$.**